# Difference between a Java interpreter and JVM

Tags: java, programming-languages, interpreter

I have heard people saying "a JVM is necessarily a Java interpreter but a Java interpreter is not necessarily a JVM". Is that true?

I mean is there a difference between a Java interpreter and JVM?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

**Java virtual machine:**

A software "execution engine" that safely and compatibly executes the byte codes in Java class files on a microprocessor (whether in a computer or in another electronic device).

**Java interpreter:**

A module that alternately decodes and executes every statement in some body of code. The Java interpreter decodes and executes bytecode for the Java virtual machine.

The Java interpreter is actually a part of JVM. Virtual machine is not just executing the bytecodes, it has lot of tasks to do. That full-fledged environment is referred to as a JVM.

Check:

- *[Java Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine)*
- *[Java SE HotSpot at a Glance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136373.html)*

Comment: "The Java interpreter is actually a part of JVM." You mean the Java *bytecode* interpreter is a part of JVM...because the JVM doesn't even see Java code.

Comment: Although, that would not be entirely correct either, because, like you said, the JVM is more than just an interpreter - it does optimizations with its JIT compiler that would otherwise make Java untenable for applications with performance empahsis.

Answer (score 8):

Simply put, a JVM interprets bytecode and a Java interpreter interprets Java. They are different because bytecode and Java are different languages.

**Bytecode** is a low-level language, like machine code. The bytecode is meant to be run by a program called a bytecode interpreter, also called a **virtual machine**. The purpose of bytecode is to be *easy to interpret*.

**Java** is a higher-level language, like C or Python. These languages can be interpreted too: you just write a program that can run their code. It doesn't have to involve bytecode. It's just that higher-level languages are harder to interpret directly.

Java is usually "interpreted" by translating the Java program into a bytecode program first. Then the **Java Virtual Machine** (JVM) runs the bytecode.

But you could interpret any language this way. The JVM could interpret other languages if you translated them into the right bytecode.

You can also interpret a programming language directly, without any bytecode. Some BASIC interpreters just look for BASIC instructions in the sourcecode and execute them. They don't make make a new program in a different language first. If you did the same thing for Java, it would be a Java interpreter but not a JVM.

Answer (score 0):

For one, code from (theoretically) any language can be compiled down to JVM bytecodes to allow execution within that environment. A Java interpreter is only able to run Java code.

Comment: I think that's incorrect. As far as I know, a Java interpreter is no more bound to Java than the JVM is. The actual Java-language code is traditionally compiled, after that it's byte code, which is interpreted and/or otherwise executed in/by the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a JVM a Java interpreter is incorrect.  The JVM is a JIT compiler that compiles and runs byte-code.  Other languages can be compiled into byte-code targeted for the JVM.  [Wikipedia article detailing such languages.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages)

Comment: That's not strictly true. The JVM will run the code in interpreted mode for a while before deciding which bits to compile. So, yes, the JVM is a Java Bytecode (class file) interpreter.

Comment: @Danny: There is no "the" JVM. There are multiple JVM implementations from different vendors on different platforms that don't necessarily all work the same.

Comment: Hey, I wasn't the first person to mention "the JVM"! Depends what you mean by "work the same". They all execute bytecode, and provide a mapping to underlying OS functions like threads, files, etc. Some of them don't have JIT (which would add to my argument that saying "the JVM is a JIT compiler" is inaccurate), some of them have different thread models (vis JRockit's old m:n model), some have different GC algorithms, but they all essentially do the same thing. But it is NOT accurate to say "the JVM is a JIT compiler".

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it...

A Java interpreter executes lines of byte code as commands to be executed.  The byte code is executed.

The JVM takes the byte code and generates machine code.  The byte code is compiled to machine code, and the machine code is executed.

Comment: **A** JVM need not necessarily include a JIT compiler.  Some of those that do include a JIT compiler have an option to disable it. `-Xint` on mine.

Answer (score 0):

java virtual machine is a virtual processor and a java interpreter is **java** tool.thanks

Comment: Edit your answer to include some valuable information and references.